# Ubuntu 18.04 gdm3 login loop

Tags: 18.04, login, login-screen

I am currently using gdm3 destop manager while I login it gets stuck in login loop.

- I have followed almost all the procedures suggested in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop#:%7E:text=Just%20log%20in%20here%20with,which%20should%20now%20look%20different)
- Permissions of Xauthority and  /tmp were fine.
- Added `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`  and updated after it as well.

But none of them worked.

I created a new user when I try to login through it there is no login loop. I am able to login properly. Why am I not able to use the original user. I'm really not understanding what to do. Can someone please help.

Comment: I'm not clear what issue you have? Do you have (1) a login-loop, or do you have (2) a wrong password issue? How did you create a new user, if you are not able to login?

Comment: With gdm3 I'm having login issue. You can get CLI by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F3` when you are in login screen. Now I can access CLI using which I created new user.When I uninstall gdm3 and install lightdm then I'm getting wrong password issue.

Comment: OK. When you CTRL+ALT+F3, then you are able to login with your original user, and this user has admin (sudo) privileges?

Comment: Yes it has admin privileges

Comment: OK. Login loops happen when Gnome Shell crashes just after GDM authenticates you. Usually there is no "wrong password" message, and this is what was confusing me from your original post, but I see you've edited that. The permissions on the user's `.Xauthority` file are just one cause, but I suspect you've already checked that; just double check by doing `ls -l` in the user's home directory and make sure nothing is owned by `root`.

Comment: `.Xauthority` permisions are with user. I even checked `ls -l` in the user's home directory and made sure nothing was owned by root.

Comment: OK. Let's check if there are any other files ~not~ owned by you in your home directory. Login using `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F3`, again, and execute the following `find $HOME -not -user $USER -exec ls -lad {} \;`. Let me know what you find.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I ran the above given command. It said /home/user/.cache/dconf, /home/user/.cache/doc, /home/user/dbus/session-bus/ is owned by root.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If not, I can suggest on more thing to try. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are able to login to Gnome Shell using the new user you had created, this implies that the issue is with your existing user, and not a Gnome Shell issue. (Issues with Gnome Shell usually have similar symptoms).

Check if there are any files *not* owned by you in your home directory.

Login using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>, again, and execute the following:

```
find $HOME -not -user $USER -exec ls -lad {} \;
```

**Option 1: Fix These File Permissions**

1. For each file or directory NOT owned by you, execute:

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER <file or directory path>
   ```

   Based on your comment above, you can execute the following commands on the parent directories:

   ```
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache
   sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/dbus
   ```
2. Then, see if you can successfully login to your desktop environment.

**Option 2: Remove These Files**

I don't think think you should have these files (`.cache/dconf`, `.cache/doc`, and `dbus`) in your home directory at all. I suspect that you ran a graphical program as root. If you have done this, **never** run any graphical program using sudo. (Insetad, use the `admin:` parameter; for example `nautilus admin:/path/to/directory`).

In any case Ubuntu should run fine without the `.cache/dconf`, `.cache/doc`, and `dbus` files or directories.

1. Try removing these files to a backup location.

   ```
   sudo mkdir /home/temp
   sudo mv ~/.cache/dconf /home/temp
   sudo mv ~/.cache/doc /home/temp
   sudo mv ~/dbus /home/temp
   ```
2. Then, see if you can successfully login to your desktop environment.
3. If everything works, delete the backed up files.

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /home/temp
   ```

Comment: I tried both the methods but none of them worked.